# How do I display a back-end error in the front-end in Angular?

Tags: angular, error-handling, angular-material, frontend, angular-errorhandler

I'm trying to display an error, generated by the back-end, in the front-end developed in Angular material. I want that the error message is displayed into an alert window. My problem is that the error message is displayed only in the console, while the message displayed in the alert window is "undefined". How can I deal with this problem?

service.ts:

```
export class UserService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public createUser(user: User): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.post<User>('http://localhost:8080/users/reg', user)
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );;
  }
private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.status === 0) {
      // A client-side or network error occurred.
      console.error('An error occurred:', error.error);
    } else {
      // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
      // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong.
      console.error(
        `Backend returned code ${error.status}, body was: `, error.error);

    }
   
    return throwError(
      'Something bad happened; please try again later.');
  }


}
```

component.ts:

```
public createUser(message: string, action: string, createForm:NgForm ) {
    this.userService.createUser(createForm.value).subscribe(
      (response: User) => {
        this.user=response;
        console.log(response);
        console.log(createForm.value);
        this._snackBar.open(message, action);
        createForm.reset();
      },
      (error: HttpErrorResponse)=>{
        alert(error.message);
        createForm.reset();
      }
    )
  }
```

The following is the screenshot of the console which displays the message error that I want to show in the alert window:
[image]

When I change `alert(error.message)` with `console.error('foo', error);` the console says:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the method "handleError", you are returning a string:

```
return throwError(
      'Something bad happened; please try again later.');
```

So, when you subscribe, you'll receive the string `'Something bad happened; please try again later.'`

If you want the subscriber to receive the message, change your handleMessage return value:

```
return throwError(error);
```

Comment: Thanks, I followed your suggesrtion and changed the return value of my `handleError method`. Now, the alert window shows the entire error and not the error message. Do you know how to display the error message?

Comment: which error message do you want to display ? if you want `handleErrors` to compute the message to display, then make it so `throwError` contains that message ?

Comment: the object `error` has a field called `message` and I want to display the value of this field. Even if I write `return throwError(error.message);` the alert window doesn't display the message field, it displays: `Http failure response for http://localhost:8080/users/reg: 400 OK` which isnt the value of the field `message` that I have stored in the back-end

Comment: I have edited my question with a screenshot that displays the message that I want to show in the alert window.

Comment: change your `alert(error.message);` into `console.error('foo', error)`, adn show me what is the result ?

Comment: I've edited the question with another screenshot to let you see the result

Comment: So, you have to do `alert(error.error.message)` ;)